# Slang for Nation with Large Army

Tags: phrase-requests, figurative

Is there a figurative/metaphorical term for a nation (or perhaps business, etc.) that has a very powerful military? I'm looking for something to parallel "deep pockets," like:

> Ancient Persia was an empire with deep pockets and (a/an) ____ ____.

I don't think the Rooseveltian "big stick" would be immediately obvious to a reader, so I'm excluding that off the bat.

Comment: Perhaps a [*well-funded war machine?*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22well-funded+war+machine%22) Do you want the reference to be positive, negative, or neutral?

Comment: ...and an army to match.

Comment: I would say "top dog" or some such.

Comment: I take a question's criteria loosely. Like the story in the Talmud, a woman sends her servant to the market for a colander, but cautions her "Don't bring me anything with holes." Personally, I'd buy the colander.

Comment: What's wrong with "big army"?

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a term for the nation or for the force itself?

Comment: The anachronism aside, you could paraphrase Mae West: “Hey Alexander, is that some **heavy artillery** in your deep pockets, or are you just glad to see me?”

Comment: If you want to match 'deep pockets' why not try 'tall/ broad-shouldered/ burly soldiers' or 'big battalions' or some such.

FYI, 'tall soldiers' was my own first thought and when I Googled it for inspiration, I found that having tall soldiers can be vital: https://www.quora.com/Do-tall-soldiers-have-an-advantage-during-war-Have-countries-with-people-of-tall-stature-benefited-from-such-height-advantages

Answer (score 1):

> Ancient Persia was an empire with deep pockets and a huge arsenal.

That might do for what you want.
But, if not, just a little more thinking might get your term.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer - Yeah, the more formal form would be "bigly arsenal".

Comment: Maybe not. deep slang, but "deep pockets" is not far from it . The problem is,, much deeper into slang, and the intention might be compromised...... for example "full quiver", , "loaded ammo box"., "long sword" might work but anything deeper into slang might not convey the proper meaning.

Comment: Right now , only "loaded for bear" comes to mind

Comment: There's always "armed to the teeth".

Comment: "big arsenal". Snigger.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [**800 pound gorilla**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/800%E2%80%93pound%20gorilla):

> *one that is dominating or uncontrollable because of great size or power*